# Hidden Windows 8 taskbar button?

Tags: windows-8, notification-area

Whenever I double click this portion (between icon and expand arrow) of the Windows 8 taskbar, the network bar slides.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZbFT.png]

Why is it so?
Some kind of hidden function?

Comment: My guess is that you have a notification icon there but for whatever reason it didn't load the image, so it is transparent or one pixel wide. Don't think it's a hidden function. I don't see that happen for me.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will hide icons in the system tray, so that you only have a few showing. The arrow next to it, and that gap, are both hotspot clickable to expand to the entire list of system tray icons. If you right-click between the last icon and the clock you can 'customize notification icons' and select the box at the bottom to 'show all', and then it will no longer hide them. If you want to further customize it you can right-click on the bar the the left of the arrow and select 'properties', and you will see 'Notification area' "customize".